# Loving texture paint - How can I make a square 'pixel' brush?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

**UPDATE: It turns out all I needed to do was just use a very low res texture for what I was trying to achieve (32x32...etc).**

I'm loving the texture paint mode inside Blender but I want to set myself up to create pixel like textures for my 3D models.

Is it possible to make a square brush? How would I go about this?

Also, any other advice / tips on tailoring Blender for pixel like texturing is also welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: maybe you'll have an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21001/how-to-get-a-square-brush-in-texture-paint

Comment: Forgot about that post, but it also didn't account for how to get the tight stroke and didn't cover using it as a brush mask texture.

Comment: Don't add Solved to the title of the question please; accept the provided answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an image rendered by setting up a plane with a shadeless material, looking through an orthographic camera.
[image]
Then you can set that resulting image up as a brush mask, and the key is to set it up to calculate alpha and to clip, not to repeat. Here I set up the spacing of the brush to be 40%, and the mapping of the brush mask texture at 200% to get the right amount of brush radius. Also, I set it to use the full hard brush curve so that it would fill well.
[image: settings]
I did also think maybe you could[image: square] just user the image I have made so here you go.

Comment: Thanks. When I try and set that up though I get some fading on the colours which are painted.

https://i.imgur.com/YJBe21z.png

Any clues how I prevent that?

Comment: Use the full hard curve setting and scale the texture to 200 for the brush so that there is plenty of brush and no fall off used for the brush.

Comment: Ah yes, the hard curve sorted that out.

The problem with this approach I have is nothing is snapped to any sort of grid. Each 'pixel' can be offset, which means it's impossible to make things look consistent....etc

What I'm interested to try and replicate is the behaviour and setup exhibited here: https://youtu.be/PCx-kBndTqQ?t=9m29s

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is not a square brush then, it is just painting onto a very low resolution image with a regular brush set to 1 pixel size. That means you won't get a large image until you upscale it, but then when you do you need to be sure to turn off the filtering so that you don't use antialias and ruin your pixelization.

Comment: Yup! I just logged in to say that's how I achieved it. Thanks!