# How can I make a pixel brush that works in Paint and Texture Paint view in Blender 2.9?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, pixel-art

Have tried following [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111860/loving-texture-paint-how-can-i-make-a-square-pixel-brush), but the best I can achieve is a pixel brush that sometimes works in Texture Paint view, but bleeds horribly in Paint view.

This brush uses a texture of a white square island surrounded by alpha 0, as seen here: (note this is invisible, but trust me, the texture is there)

[image]
[image]

Does anybody know how to create a pixel brush that works reliably in Paint and Texture Paint views? (And, ideally, which swaps out the cursor so I can see the brush texture outline?)